# What is the best way to find someone to help critique my work?

Tags: web, business, stock-photography

I'm a medical student who is looking to submit images to shutterstock and hopefully pay down a little bit of debt. I have my own website but I'm having a hard time finding anyone online to review my images ( I need to pick 10). Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

[Fred Miranda](http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/) has in my opinion the best photography community on the internet right now. Try the appropriate Presentation board or the Photo Critique board.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find som photographers assocation near you loaction.
I think that you can find there many good or very good photographers. And they can look at your photos and critique your work.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how professional you are, or what kind of processing you use for your work (if you do). But I can tell that most of the pictures that you show on your webpage lack of something that makes them special, or yours. On the other hand, there's a couple of pictures that I loved as in compositional terms. I don't make a living out of photography, and either my work has never been exposed to criticism. I'm not even over 18, but take my advice and pay more attention to the basics of composition and look for ways to make the spectator's eyes get into the photograph. If you don't mind to answer, how high do you consider your level of experience in photography? And excuse me for my language if it may not sound right (i'm from Spain).
Answering to your main question, if you have the time check Jared Polin on Youtube. He has a section of photography critique, for which you can apply by using his site. Also try to show your work to the public in a cultural centre or something of that kind wherever it is that you live in.